# Support for Categorical columns in Deltalake (the file format)?

Tags: delta-lake, apache-arrow

I have some large tables where some columns are low-cardinality but contain memory-heavy entries.

The classic example would be a denormlaized transaction table with a product description field.

This is a column with hundreds of millions of records, but only ~1,000 unique entries, each ~500 characters long.

So far I've worked with this by using the Arrow categorical data type, which is supported by parquet, but now that I'm exploring Delta as a file format I see that this is not supported.

Is this on the roadmap? Or is there a workaround?